# In APC-Detrended Analysis: Testing for Significant Difference in Cohort Variable Coefficients, Beyond Z-Test

Tags: statistical-significance, regression-coefficients

I have conducted an APC-Detrended analysis.
Among the results, I want to test whether there is a significant difference in the coefficient values of the Cohort variable **especially between the two groups colored with yellow(cohort 1945-1954) and green(cohort 1955-1964)**.

I have already tried the Z-test, but it did not show significant results.

Besides the Z-test, are there any other tests I can try?

For your reference and better understanding of my analysis results, I have attached some of the results below.

[image]